# stackoverflowのページがブラウザーウィンドウ幅が狭いとレイアウトが変わる？

Tags: バグ, デザイン

題記の通りなのですが、stackoverflowのページがGoogle Chromeで開くと、本来縦に3カラムのレイアウトの筈が、「ホーム、質問、タグ」などのサイドバー的カラム、「質問一覧などの本文カラム」の2カラムレイアウトになり、質問一覧などの本文カラムの下にメタでのお勧めや、文章の整え方などのアシスト情報カラムが本文の下に回り込んでしまっています。

考えようによっては質問カラムが広く取れて良いのですが、見えなくなったと思っていた一番右のカラムが、スクロールしていくと一番下に表示されるのでびっくりします。

現在の所試したブラウザーは

- 2カラムレイアウトになってしまう　→　Google Chrome
- 3カラムレイアウト（いつも通り）　→　Safari, Vivaldi

です。この現象が発生しているのは僕の所だけでしょうか？

Comment: 私の環境だとWindowsのChrome 71.0.3578.98ではuBlock Origin等の拡張機能も使用していますが特に問題無さそうです。

Comment: 画面横幅を狭くすると2カラムになることはあるように思います。画面幅を広くしても2カラムのままでしょうか？（幅が狭いとき2カラムになるのはバグか仕様かどっちなのでしょう……）

Comment: 3カラム目を下に追い出すスレッシュホールドが幅400pxなんですね。cssの数字が変わったのか、ブラウザーの幅を気がつかずに変えてしまったのか解りませんが、ブラウザーの幅を400px以上取ることで解決しました。

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange におそらく同一の話が投稿されているのを見つけました: [Helpful sidebar content is down below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314445/341401)

Comment: このアナウンスですね。ではバグでは無いと言うことで、この質問は削除した方がいいでしょうか？

Comment: @Чайка コメント欄でのやり取りから分かった結果を「回答」として投稿する形で大丈夫だと思います。

Comment: @Чайка さん、要望として残すことはできます。実際右カラムが下に動くのはやや変な気がするので、バグだと言って Stack Exchange チームの判断を仰ぐこともできます。個人的にもこの動作には違和感を覚えるので、下に動くかわりにどうして欲しいかを書いていただけると反応をもらえるかもしれません。

Comment: また、仮に何かしらの報告がバグじゃないと分かったとしても「それはバグじゃない」という情報は有益です。「バグかも？」レベルでも是非ご投稿頂ければ :)

Answer (score 1):

nekketsuuuさんのコメントより、画面が狭い場合、ブラウザーの幅が狭い場合、右のサイドバーがコンテンツエリアの下に回り込む提案があり、それが採用されたらしい事が解りました。
[Helpful sidebar content is down below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314445/341401)

しかしながら、今回の対応は今ひとつ見やすいとは言いにくいので、

幅が充分あるときは

```
--------------------------------------------------
|左|   メインコンテンツ         |
|サ|                           | 右サイドバー
|イ|                           |
|ド|                           |
|バ|                           |
|ー|                           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

幅が不足していると感じているとき(現在のスレッシュホールドは400px)

```
--------------------------------------------------
|左　　|   メインコンテンツ
|サイド|
|バー　|
|------|
|元右　|
|サイド|
|バー　|
--------------------------------------------------
```

という表示になった方がユーザーフレンドリーだと思います。
（もしかしたら下案だと、そもそも3カラムレイアウトにする必要が無く、最初からサイドバーとコンテンツの2カラムレイアウトで充分わかりやすい気もします。左サイドバーは数行使っただけでがら空きですし）

Comment: あ、いえ、"Helpful sidebar content is down below" は「今は下へ回り込むようになっているけど、これは悪いデザインだと思うので×××に変えたい」という内容です。分かりにくくてすいません。